# Use a font which isn't installed in user's environment, without installing it prior to use

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, sudo, administrator

If I would like to use a custom font in my project which I know isn't widely distributed. Is there a possibility to use it without installing it on the user's machine (or what OS they are running) (I don't know whether I'll get su / administrator privilege).

Alternatively, and less conveniently, is there an option to render the text in real-time to a image and present the image (not ideal because then you can't copy any text).

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need su priviledges for installing fonts locally such as in `~/.local/share`

Comment: @sshashank124 in Windows in order to access fonts folder admin privilege is needed